# 503 errors (Service Unavailable) on Azure Websites

Tags: iis, azure, azure-web-app-service

I keep getting this 503 error on all my Standard Azure Websites on West Europe.
I've tried restarting the App pool, and also tried scaling down and then up again.
Am I missing something or could it be an error at Microsoft?

Comment: Same issue, West Europe too. Probably an outage that hasn't been detected and/or reported yet. Had the same problem last Tuesday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are experiencing the same problem here. I already opened a support ticket and received the following answer:

> Thank you for contacting Microsoft Support. This case is related to an
>   incident currently occurring. We have a team that handles all cases
>   related to incidents such as this. We will transfer your case to that
>   team. Once that transfer takes place, here is what you can expect to
>   happen.
>
> 1. We will send you regular updates on the status of the incident. This information is the same information available from the Azure
>      Status Page located at
>      http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current. However, instead of
>      requiring that you check the status page, we will push the information
>      to you in email.
> 2. Once the incident has been mitigated, we will inform you with another notification, after which point your case will be closed.

Now Microsoft is showing the error on its Azure Status website.

Websites in North Europe are working. So we will setup a Traffic Manager on Azure with method "Failover". In case of problems in West Europe the Traffic Manager will automatically route all connections to the mirrored website in North Europe.
See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/